# Fade the li when modal is opened and added to other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

When I clicked on the product, it opened the Modal and added to the My product list but I want that particular product to get faded if it is added to the My Product list and the button also when the modal is reopened so that it could not be added again to list.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!--This is the code what i'm able to do so far-->
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('button[id^="allttm"]').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
 var $this = $(this);
  var data_id = $this.attr('data-id');
$("#mylist").append('<li class="has-item">' + data_id + '</li>');
 });
});
</script>

<ul class="unstyled" id="products">
<li class="dummycontent" id="itemdetail" data-id="6425809">
    <a class="dummyclass" href="javascript:void(0)" id="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">
<span class="itemname">product 1</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
<h3 id="myproductlistheader">My productlist</h3>
<ol id="mylist" class="productlist">
</ol>
```

This the modal area:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
  </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
<div class="procuctifo">
  <div>
  <h3 class="productheading">product 1</h3>
</div>
</div>
   </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="allttm_1" data-id="product 1">Add to list</button>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'diable a li'? li's have no functionality to disable? are you binding an event to the li's? or do you mean 'a' tags inside li's?

Comment: @atmd i Mean to fade it sorry for that but disable the button in modal

Answer (score 0):

you can add another class to your product item once it has been added to the list and based on whether the product items has the class or not you can add it to the list.your code may look something like this:

```
$('.products').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('added')){
        //product in the list , no need to add

    }else{
        // add class and add product to list
        $(this).addClass('added');
        //add product to list
    }
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This i Know i Want when i open a modal on perticular product and on the modal Add to List button is there It adds the Product to my list  and When added only Then it should get Faded Not before..